# Playback error E/ExoPlayer exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error (While playing from internal storage) with network its working

Tags: android, ios, flutter, kotlin, dart

```
VideoPlayerController.contentUri(Uri.parse(widget.videoUrl))
        ..initialize().then((value) {
          videoPlayerController.play();
          videoPlayerController.setVolume(1);
        });
```

That code is giving me this error

> Playback error E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5579):
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5579):       at
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:632)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5579):       at
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:604)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5579):       at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5579):       at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(
> 5579):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5579):   Caused by:
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5579):       at
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource.open(FileDataSource.java:121)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5579):       at
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:258)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5579):       at
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5579):       at
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1009)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5579):       at
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5579):       at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5579):       at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5579):       at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) E/flutter ( 5579):
> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception:
> PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error,
> null, null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's weird, but

```
VideoPlayerController.network()
```

works for local path also.

Answer (score 0):

```
initState((){VideoPlayerController.network();});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how/why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.